# Should I bother feeding my pets?

Tags: elona-plus

So half the times I die in Elona+, 'tis not due to beast nor arrow, but the implacable foe known as **Hunger**.

Fortunately, my adventurer developed a taste for human flesh, so food is less of an issue now. However, I've noticed that I can give meals to my pets as well, and they will eat them. Now I *know* I've not been diligent about getting them vittles, but at the same time, I've yet to see them starve to death.

So... is it okay to leave my pets starving wrecks? What's the worst that could happen?

Answer (score 2):

The worst that can happen is that your pet gets impregnated, births an alien child in town, who then proceeds to impregnate the rest of the town, turning it into a wasteland filled with aliens who will attack you on sight.

Now, that's not a very *likely* scenario, but it could certainly happen.  When you don't feed your pet, they will drink from fountains, and that has a host of things that can happen, one of which is the above.  Other things are your pet randomly falling in and drowning (and thereby causing you to pay for their resurrection).  [Whatever can happen from drinking from a fountain](http://elona.wikia.com/wiki/Fountains), they might get it.

The other bad thing is that they will eat rotten food when hungry, too.  Strangely, they won't eat any rotten food they're carrying, but if you drop some on the ground, they go for it like starving wolves.

Now, it's not ALL bad.  They won't starve at all, so you don't need to worry about your pet keeling over from hunger.  But there are [good things that can happen from eating](http://elona.wikia.com/wiki/Food#Types_of_Food), and those apply to your pet as well.  If you want them to train certain stats, make sure to give them food that does so.  And keeping them full ensures that they won't eat that corpse that just dropped, that gives you the training YOU want.

Comment: Bonus note: you can tell if your pet is hungry if you use a stethoscope on them. The health bar will be green if hungry, pink if full. A tamer's whip would also stop the whole rotten/fountain problem.

Comment: *You use the stethoscope on the little girl* "Y-y-you pervert". O.o

Comment: @RavenDreamer She says the same thing when you use a leash on them.  Welcome to Elona, where the crazy is normal.